# How can we follow/Unfollow instagram in android app?

Tags: android, api, instagram

When I use Follow/Unfollow API in instagram. I give me error like that.

Error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}
```

My Post method Call is here.

```
public static AllMessage postAction(String action, String UserID, String mAccessToken, DefaultHttpClient httpClient) {
    AllMessage ReturnMessage = new AllMessage();
    String url = String.format(RELATIONSHIP_URL, new Object[]{UserID, mAccessToken});
    Log.v("log_tag", "FolURL " + url);
    try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        params.setParameter("action=", action);
        if (httpClient == null) {
            httpClient = OpenHttpClientConnection();
        }
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> arrayList = new ArrayList(2);
        arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", action));

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", String.valueOf(arrayList));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList, "UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(ent);
        String mHttpReturnedData = readInputStreamToString(httpClient.execute(httpPost).getEntity().getContent());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Return " + mHttpReturnedData);
       } catch (Exception e4) {
        ReturnMessage.MessageType = "Unsupported Format";
        ReturnMessage.MessageError = "Unsupported data format Error -1000";
        ReturnMessage.ActionSucess = false;
        ReturnMessage.ActionID = 0;
        ReturnMessage.PrvAction = action;
    }
    return ReturnMessage;
}
```

Please help me for this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first register your app to use the **Instagram API**

The link is here **https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/**

Then you comunicate with the endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
and make the proper calls.

Currently there is not an **Android SDK** made by them that I have heard of, but I'm pretty sure there has to be a **3rd party** out there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have only error when i use POST method. In Get Method there is no any error. So do u have any suggestion??

Comment: Can you update your question info with the POST code?

Comment: I have used Asynctask Method. I call this function on asynctask.               PostData.postAction("unfollow", str_UserID, mApp.getTOken(), httpClient); And above is the code for that method.

Comment: Found your problem, it has nothing to do with your code, your code is good. You need to go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/ and submit a permission review for what you are trying to accomplish once you get approved it should work.

Sorry for the delay.